# Installing yo & generator-code on xubuntu

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, sudo, nodejs, npm

So I have been trying to install yo & generator-code for xubuntu to try making some vs code extensions,
I installed nodejs & npm via sudo apt-get
then did `sudo npm install -g yo generator-code`
then when I tried to run `yo -v or yo code` I get the following error

```
    filePatterns: lookups.flatMap(prefix => [`${prefix}/*/index.ts`, `${prefix}/*/index.js`, `${prefix}/*/index.cjs`, `${prefix}/*/index.mjs`]),
                          ^

TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function
    at Environment.resolver.lookup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js:70:27)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:130:7)
    at pre (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:89:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:219:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

I realized later that sudo wasn't the best approach so I made a new directory for npm-packages and then set the prefix to it

```
mkdir "/programming/.npm-global"
npm config set prefix "/programming/.npm-global"
gedit ~/.profile
```

to which I added
`export PATH=~/programming/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
then I did

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
```

now when I run `yo code` I get

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js:70
    filePatterns: lookups.flatMap(prefix => [`${prefix}/*/index.ts`, `${prefix}/*/index.js`, `${prefix}/*/index.cjs`, `${prefix}/*/index.mjs`]),
                          ^

TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function
    at Environment.resolver.lookup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js:70:27)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:130:7)
    at pre (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:89:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:219:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

and if I run
`sudo yo code`

I get

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:128
            throw err;
            ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/insight-nodejs/insight-yo.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Conf.get store [as store] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:108:18)
    at Conf.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:47:27)
    at Insight.get optOut [as optOut] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:52:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:208:48)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I was able to fix this issue
I did the following

```
npm remove yo

npm remove generator-code

sudo apt remove npm

sudo apt update

sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall libssl-dev

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash

nvm install 16.11.0

npm config delete prefix

npm install -g npm

npm install yo generator-code

yo code
```